# Fxml and Spring in JavaFX2 - How to define Dependency Injection

Tags: spring, javafx-2, fxml

As far as I could get, with an fxml file you can abstract your user interface design (or any other class actually) within a fxml configuration file and load it after.
On the other hand, with Spring configuration one could define the DI for the application. So, I'm trying to figure out how to combine this together.

Example,suppose I have a scene where 4 graphs are displayed. Now I want to display a 5th one. To do so, (theoretically) should I add an entry to my spring.xml configuration file to inject a new graph and additionally add a new entry into my fxml file do set this new graph design configuration?

I'm trying to have a broad understand of how this would work so I'm sorry if my question lacks some technical accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FXML I would define the graph control and the container for the graphs which would allow 0 to N graphs to be displayed in a grid, list or other layout.  The controller for the graph container would load a graph control and add it to the container based on a button click or whatever else.

I do not know how you intend to control your program so I have left some blanks there to fill in.  Don't be too quick to configure everything in spring, do whatever is simplest. I use DI to wire dependencies to controllers which have all the logic.

Comment: Exactly, I was referring to DI in the controller,where the logic is. Do you use Spring to do that?